# How to access SelectedItem of ComboBox inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, binding

I have following XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="TextComboPairItemsControl" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllHeaders.Fields}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="{Binding}"
                                   Grid.Column="0" Margin ="2"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.Tags}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.TextComboPairList.Combo}"
                                  Grid.Column="1" Margin ="2" SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="True"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Now, in my code I want to be able to read what the user has chosen in each ComboBox. For that I created a class:

```
public class TextComboPair
{
    public string TextContent { get; set; }
    public string ComboContent { get; set; }
}
```

Every pair of TextBlock and ComboBox would have its own object of the above class.
I also created a list to store all those pairs of data:

```
public List<TextComboPair> TextComboPairList 
{
    get; 
    set; 
}
```

It is defined in my DataContext.

So, if, for example, there was displayed a list of three TextBlock-ComboBox pairs on the screen and user would choose what he needs in each ComboBox, I'd like to have the above List populated with that data.

As you can see in XAML I bound Selected Item to this List, but I must have done it wrong.

Hwo can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=DataContext.Tags, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl }}}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl }}, Path=DataContext.TextComboPairList.Combo}"
                              Grid.Column="1" Margin ="2" SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="True"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. My list is still null. Actually with this code, my ComboBox doesn't even show any content. maybe because I don't have any DataGrid.

Comment: then what is mainGrid?

Comment: Well, it's just Grid, not DataGrid

Comment: Try replacing that DataGrid with ItemsControl... May be that will help you or the parent control which has a DataContext you want...

Comment: Could you edit your answer, so that I could see what you mean? I'm fairly new to WPF and XAML.

Comment: I pasted your code - ComboBoxes have content as they should, but SelectedIndex="0" doesn't work - the initial selection of every ComboBox is nothing, when it should show element from "0" index. And still, my list of combobox selections is null

Comment: Another thing: why did you change ItemsSource? It was working correctly. Does it also have impact on SelectedItem?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to somehow read combobox selections from codebehind?

Comment: Loreno, I dont know how you written dataclasses or where exactly these properties are?.. then how we can post exact solution which you want... you just posted few of the code samples...